# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Tags: c#

I don't know what to do because the error is in the `Form1.Designer.cs` and because I have no experience in debugging that part of the program.

```
//Form1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 246);
this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.Name = "Form1";
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.Text = "Generate Username";
this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
this.groupBox2.PerformLayout();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Comment: What errors do you get ? Can you post it.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting error on these lines ? double click on the error and specify the line you are getting that error

Comment: Do you have a TextBox control named Text?

Comment: The error is on this.Name = "Form1";

Comment: @user3248531, then you probably have a control named "Name"

Comment: @user3248531, do you have textBox with `ID` `Name` ?

Comment: You have textbox named `Name`, rename it to `txtName` in designer and your code should be good

Comment: Ah! There is a textbox named Name. I already debugged my program. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The error is on this.Name = "Form1";

I suspect you have created a control named `Name`, which conflicts with the `Name` property of the window. Just rename the control to something else and it should work again.

Comment: I solved my problem sir. Thanks! As you have said, there is a textbox named Name so it has conflicts. Thanks for answering! :)

Answer (score 7):

The error must come from somewhere else, there's nothing here with a `TextBox`. The error is probably caused by assigning a string to a TextBox itself instead of assigning a string to the `Text` property of the TextBox.

### Example:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb = "Default text";
```

This should be:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = "Default text";
```

Otherwise you have created a control with a name like `Name` or `Text`, in which case you'll have to rename it to `NameTextBox` or something.