# Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have tried below solutions for that but still its giving me same error :
[Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434483/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-windows-forms-textbox)

**Here is my code of form elements :**

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
{
         this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
            this.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.On;
            this.Name = "UserForm"; // Here I have a problem while runing the application
            this.Text = "User Log Management";
}
```

I have tried to change the name of Form but still its not working.

**Here is the Snap for code :**
[image: Here is the Snap for code]
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `TextBox` control on your form that you have called `Name`? That's a bad idea!

Comment: Its taking by default while compiling the application

Comment: Yes, you still have a conflict because of the text box control that is also on your form. See my answer.

Comment: I've just realised the question you linked has exactly the same problem, you should really have read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `TextBox` control on your form that you have called `Name`. That is causing a conflict. Rename your text box to something distinct. A common convention in WinForms development is to use control prefixes (or suffixes). For example `txt` for text boxes. e.g. `txtName`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246546/best-practices-for-c-sharp-gui-naming-conventions) for further discussion on naming.

Answer (score 5):

One of the text boxes in your form has an ID of "Name". Rename it to "txtName" and your code should work fine

Comment: Thank you, Its really help me to find the conflict.